# Text reading and list index out of range in Python

Tags: python, text

I have a text that has 8 rows. The program will read this text and match the word in the text with the word that user enters. But python gives a mistake:

```
satir=dosya.readlines()[a]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is my code:

```
a=0
c=0
while a<8:
    satir=dosya.readlines()[a]
    a=a+1
    for i in olasilik:
        if ((olasilik[c]+"\n")==satir):
            c=c+1
            print(olasilik[c])
```

Comment: why not try printing `a` right before you call `readlines()[a]`?

Comment: you don't have an index 8 `while a < 7` or better yet just loop over readlines

Comment: although I suspect that is just the first of many issues with this code ...

Comment: Note that, *each* time through the `while` loop, you are reading the entire file; that really only works the first time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This would probably work better:

```
for satir in dosya.readlines():
  for o in olasilik:
    if ("%s\n" % o) == satir:
      print o
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much. It has worked. Can i ask what "%s\n" % o means?

Comment: You are welcome! It's a more "Pythonic way" of doing string concatenation. It will do the automatic str() conversion for your variables: 
`str(o) + "\n" == "%s\n" % o` 
It allows you to do so easy str formatting like: 
`"%s == %s is not %s" % (1, 1.1, True)` 
will return '1 == 1.1 is not True'

Answer (score 1):

this is not how you should do it

instead do

```
for satir in dosya:
   #do something
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `readlines()` reads all the content of the file in a list the first time you call it. The second time you call it the file is already finished and you get an empty list and you get an error trying to access element `1` of that empty list.

To loop over the lines of the file you can do

```
for L in f:
    ...
```

or

```
for L in f.readlines():
    ...
```